# With PHP, what's the proper syntax to include a variable in a link?

Tags: php, variables, hyperlink

I've seen it as

```
<a href=\"$stylesheet_path\">
```

or as

```
<a href="<?php $stylesheet_path ?>"</a>
```

None of those seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `echo` the variable `$stylesheet_path` to output it. So:

```
<a href="<?php echo $stylesheet_path; ?>"</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an [`echo`](http://php.net/echo). Do this:

```
echo "<a href=\"$stylesheet_path\">";
```

OR

```
<a href="<?php echo $stylesheet_path; ?>"</a>
```

Comment: or short tags can be used <?=$function_here?> if it is turned on

Answer (score 0):

There's also a shortcut for when you only want to do an echo in a php block:

```
<a href="<?=$stylesheet_path ?>">link</a>
```

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

Comment: Remember that `short_open_tags` in php.ini has to be enabled for this feature to work.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone had awesome answers but I'm wondering why you'd want to use a variable? If it's because the stylesheet could be different on each page then that variable would be different on a case by case basis so if it were me I could definitely see a scenario where there'd be another script that would be included in the HTML and then I'd want to use a function instead of a variable. I'd do something like

```
// some other PHP that gets you the filename or path
function getStylesheet() {
     // more code to store the correct path
     echo $styleURL
}
```

Obviously, I'm not great at this but I'm assuming you left out information about why you're doing it that way and I happen to be doing something similar so instead of using variables I'm calling a function that ends up echoing the correct path to the stylesheet I want. In most cases I think everyone else has a better answer but this is just another option to think about.